NPV acceptable performance of investment
I have started studying for a economics exam for my university.I have been studying EE and CS and the subject is called Economical Analysis.Well last semester I couldnt really attend class because I was attending another class so I decided to study on my own to pass the subject whatever.Anyway every year he gives cash inflows and outflows of a investment and a minimum performance percent and tells us to evaluate the investment using ARR ,IRR and NPV.I was really confused why IRR and NPV are not the same.
After studying I realised that a clever way to compare the performance of a investment to a required minimum of lets say 20% is to substitute 0.2 into the equation of NPV and if the NPV >= 0 then the investment is acceptable else it is not.
However what is the NPV performance tester method about?Well I have been thinking about this and I have a clue.In addition to the minimum required performance , it gives a discount rate.So I think what he is talking about on the NPV investment evaluation performance is equal to the (profitability index of the investment) - 1 * 100% .Does this make sense?The professor is kind of cold and doesnt let us ask anything during the examination so I want to get rid of this subject as quick as possible.Thanks!
